# Dismissing a modal and its caller

Tags: ios, storyboard, modal-dialog

Sorry but none of the similar questions provide a working solution.

New single-view project. 
Storyboard actions:

- VC1 is embedded in nav-controller
- a button in VC1 activates a *push* seque into VC2
- a button in VC2 activates a *modal* segue into VC3
- VC3 has a button, and a *UIViewController-subclass* to handle the button action

**Problem statement:** How can I have the button of the modal VC3 close **both** VC3 and VC2 at once, taking me back to VC1?

This did not work - takes me to VC2 only:

```
- (IBAction)dismissPressed:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *myNavController = [self navigationController];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [myNavController popToViewController:[myNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use *self.presentingViewController* to find out the "previous view controller".
You do not need to pass the previous view controller through the property.

```
- (IBAction)dismissPressed:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self.presentingViewController popViewControllerAnimated:TES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Sorry @maros - I'm totally losing you. The button of this handler is part of the modal view - I don't have to check for its type. The problem statement is how to cause the button of VC3 to take me back to VC1

Comment: @ishahak ok, now I understand your problem. I have edited my comment. Please, check it.

Comment: Hi @maros, sorry again but if you read thru the problem statement above you will see that I need to pop two VCs, while your code only dismiss the modal

Comment: Hi @ishahak, ok. Tooke me some time, I edited my answer again :) You can access to the previous view controller by self.presentingViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, here is the solution:

If you can limit yourself to ios6+, the right answer is to make the button an *unwind segue* as described in [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)

But if you are like me and must comply to ios5, the solution goes likes this:

In the VC who calls the *modal segue* declare a delegate like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueModalVC"]) {
        ModalVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.prevVC = self;
    }
}
```

You will have to #import the header for the destination modal VC.

Now in the modal VC itself add a property to hold the previous VC like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *prevVC;
```

And now the button's action for popping both VCs should look like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressedMainMenu:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[self.prevVC navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

*[EDITED to show the final version which works perfectly and can do flip animation from VC3 back to VC1. Took me hours to finalize this but now you can enjoy it for free :) ]*

IMHO the fact that the modal VC has no 'native' method to access its preceding VC is a design bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use [popToRootViewControllerAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc) method to go back VC1.

```
- (IBAction)dismissPressed:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *myNavController = [self navigationController];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [myNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    }];
}
```